# rewrite spaces to redirect to underscores when following a specific domain url string and only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to write a modrewrite that will replace a space %20 with an underscore that will look like this. http://cityinsider.com/b/ocean%20shores_wa/mikes-seafood-ocean-shores   will redirect to http://cityinsider.com/b/ocean_shores_wa/mikes-seafood-ocean-shores .  All the underscores are  permanent, but sometimes there is a space between two and three word cities. so any spaces found after only this type and part of  url: cityinsider.com/b/ need to be replaced .  So this won't effect any other url strings that don't look like the above; for example it should not work on spaces that are immediately after domain root e.g. cityinsider.com/%20/appleWood  and shoulnd't work where it doesn't follow the cityinsider.com/b/ such as cityinsider.com/c/%20

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\ ([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$1_$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```